# Actuary P/1 Exam Question

Tags: probability-distributions

[image: Problem I am having trouble with]

I was taking a practice exam and I don't understand a step in one of the solutions to the problem. I understand every part except why $f(y^{0.5})=8(y^{0.5})^{-3}$
If someone could help explain that to me it would be very helpful.

Edit: Just to be clear I am only referring to the second solution provided that starts at "Alternatively"

Comment: Basically the parameter for the function $f(y)$ was $y$, now they are just substituting $y^{0.5}$ for $y$

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo that may be the cause of the confusion. The density function $f(t)$ of $T$, for $t\gt 2$, is $\frac{8}{t^3}$. This is obtained by differentiating the cdf, which is $1-\frac{4}{t^2}$. After that, it is direct substitution of $y^{0.5}$ for $t$.

Comment: That explains everything, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.